# Generating an array response using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am a complete newbie in *Matlab*, having never used it before, and therefore don't have the slightest clue of how to generate subroutines. I have found tutorials with regards to generating matrices and solving related problems but so far nothing to help me with the following:

I want to make a subroutine to generate an array response `a(\theta)` of a uniform linear array with `M` elements and spacing `\Delta` wavelengths to a source coming from direction `\theta` degrees.

I have also been given the following code to work with: `function a = gen_a(M,Delta,theta)`

Now, as far as I'm aware, the array response `a(\theta)` is given by

```
a(\theta)=[1 ; e^{j2\pi\Delta\sin(\theta)} ; ..... ; e^{j2\pi(M-1)\Delta\sin(\theta)}]
```

If someone could demonstrate to me how this is done then at least I will have an idea of how to create subroutines for other functions.

Comment: There's no LaTeX support on SO (unfortunately), could you please rewrite your question without TeX?

Comment: @Alessiox Is that easier to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your function takes as input `delta` (wavelength), `M` (number of array elements) and `theta` (direction of arrival).

Assuming your formula is correct, your first option is to write a for-loop than runs for all array elements. Let's call `m` the array index:

```
for m=1:M
    a(m)=exp(1i*2*pi*delta*sin(theta)*(m-1));
end
```

If `theta=pi/4;` `delta=1;` and `M=10;` (just some random numbers for the sake of demo) you'll have:

```
a =

  Columns 1 through 4

   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.2663 - 0.9639i  -0.8582 + 0.5133i   0.7233 + 0.6906i

  Columns 5 through 8

   0.4731 - 0.8810i  -0.9752 - 0.2214i   0.0462 + 0.9989i   0.9506 - 0.3105i

  Columns 9 through 10

  -0.5524 - 0.8336i  -0.6564 + 0.7544i
```

In the code snippet above, `pi` is the constant π, `1i` is the imaginary unit *j* whereas `exp(x)` is a function that simply evaluates *e^x*.
This code works if `theta` is in radians; otherwise if `theta` is in degrees you must use `sind()` and not `sin()`.

The beauty of Matlab is that is actually pretty fast when it comes to vectorized expressions. Indeed there's a smart way of simplifying the code above as follows:

```
a2=exp(1i*2*pi*delta*sin(theta)*((1:M)-1));
```

and `a2` will be exactly the same as `a` evaluated above. This simplified code relies on the fact that in Matlab (most of the times) you can feed to a given function (`exp`, in our case) an entire array of values and Matlab will return the function evaluated at every point in the input array: e.g. I can evaluate `sin(pi)` and `sin(pi/2)` in a one-shot fashion thanks to `sin([pi pi/2])`, as you can see I've created an input vector and fetched such vector to `sin()`.

So, in conclusion, you can easily write your function as either

```
function a = gen_a(M,Delta,theta)
    for m=1:M
        a(m)=exp(1i*2*pi*Delta*sin(Theta)*(m-1));
    end
end
```

or

```
function a = gen_a(M,Delta,theta)
    a=exp(1i*2*pi*Delta*sin(Theta)*((1:M)-1));
end
```